# Count files in directory with Dlang

Tags: d

I would like an easy way to count the number of files in a directory using D.

As far as I can tell from the D manual, dirEntries returns a range, but this has no length property.  I therefore have to iterate through the results with a counter, or gather up the names in a traditional array which I can find the length of...  Is there a better way?

```
auto txtFiles = dirEntries(".", "*.txt", SpanMode.shallow);

int i=0;
foreach (txtFile; txtFiles)
    i++;

writeln(i, " files found..");
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ranges generally don't have a `length` property unless it can be calculated in `O(1)`. Any range which can't calculate its length in better than `O(n)` isn't going to have a `length` property, because it's too inefficient. The idiomatic way to get the length of a range with no `length` property is to use [`std.range.walkLength`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#walkLength). It uses `length` if the range defines `length`; otherwise, it simply iterates over the range and counts up how many elements there are.

You can also use [`std.algorithm.count`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#count), but it's intended for counting the number of elements which match a predicate, and while it defaults to a predicate which returns `true` for every element, that's less efficient than `walkLength`, because `walkLength` doesn't call anything on the elements as it iterates over them, and it will use `length` instead if it's been defined, whereas `count` never will.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `walkLength` will use `.length` when available, so there's no reason to worry about loss of efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`count` from `std.algorithm`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#count).

```
import std.algorithm, std.stdio, std.file;

void main() {
    writeln(count(dirEntries(".", "*.txt", SpanMode.shallow)), " files found");
}
```