# dirEntries with walklength returns no files

Tags: d

I am working with dirEntries. Great function by the way.  I wanted to test for the number of files before I used a foreach on it. I looked here on stack overflow and the suggested method was to use the walkLength function ([Count files in directory with Dlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689708/count-files-in-directory-with-dlang)).  I took that suggestion.  The return from it was a non-zero value - great. However, the foreach will not iterate over the result of dirEntries. It acts like the walkLength has left the dirEntries at the end of the range.  Is there a way to reset it so I can start at the beginning of the dirEntries list?  Here is some example code:

```
auto dFiles = dirEntries("",filter, SpanMode.shallow);
if (walkLength(dFiles) > 0)
{
    writeln("Passed walkLength function");
    foreach (src; dFiles)
    {
        writeln("Inside foreach");
    }
}
```

The output shows it gets past the walkLength function, but never gets inside the foreach iterator.

Am I using dirEntries wrong? I have looked at Ali Cehreli's great book Programming in D as someone suggest.  Nothing stuck out at me.  I have looked online and nothing points to my interpretation of the problem. Of course, I could be completely off base on what the problem really is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dirEntries` gives you a range. You consume that range with `walkLength` and reach its end. Then you attempt to read more entries from it with the `foreach` loop. However, you have already reached its end, so there is nothing more to read.

You can either repeat the `dirEntries` call, use the `array` function from std.array to convert the range to an array, or use the `.save` function to create a copy of the range that you pass to `walkLength`.

If you don't care about the length and only care about whether it's empty, you can use the `.empty` property of the range instead of `walkLength`.

Comment: Well, used the .entry and it didn't work.  When I tested an empty directory, the program blew up on the dirEntries call. So I used a try/catch.  This lead to a very strange side effect: I can't use "auto" for typing anymore.  I tried to use DirEntry at the data type for the dirEntries and compiler doesn't like it. I tried DirEntry[] and the compiler doesn't like it either.  I am sorry to be such a pain. What wrong assumption am I making here?

Comment: I figured it out my problem. dhansenan was correct.  The exception was from another location that just happened due to a typo on the command line.  My bad.